How do I fix twitchy text?
Snack (for you can see)
I try use interpolate, but i don't know how he can help with this problem.
I have this scaling problem too, but with less twitching, much less.
With scaling twitching can see only on 60hz (android), on 120hz (android) another guy not see this.
Current example on my pc (144hz) looks like blur, not like twitching.
But another guy from pc not see this, maybe he have 60hz monitor, idk.
This text twitching:
<Animated.Text style={[
                            styles.defaultText,
                            !isPressed ? styles.notPressedText : styles.pressedText,
                            {...animatedStyle}
                        ]}>Accept</Animated.Text>

Full code:

import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {ImageBackground, Pressable, StyleSheet, View} from "react-native";

import Animated, {
    Easing, Extrapolation, interpolate, useAnimatedStyle,
    useSharedValue,
    withRepeat,
    withSequence,
    withTiming
} from "react-native-reanimated";

const animationWithRepeate = (toValue: number, config: object) => withRepeat(withTiming(toValue, config), Infinity, true);

const AnimatedPressable = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Pressable);

function App() {
    const width = useSharedValue(112);
    const height = useSharedValue(36);
    const fontSize = useSharedValue(11);

    const scale = useSharedValue(1);
    const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);

    const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
        fontSize: interpolate(fontSize.value, [11, 13], [11, 13])
    }));

    const animatedSize = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
        width: interpolate(width.value, [112, 124], [112, 124]),
        height: interpolate(height.value, [36, 40], [36, 40]),
    }));

    useEffect(() => {

        width.value = animationWithRepeate(124, { duration: 400, easing: Easing.linear });
        height.value = animationWithRepeate(40, { duration: 400, easing: Easing.linear });
        fontSize.value = animationWithRepeate(13, { duration: 400, easing: Easing.linear });

        // scale.value = animationWithRepeate(scale.value, 1.1, { duration: 400, easing: Easing.linear }, Infinity);

    }, [fontSize, width, height]);

    return (
        <View
            style={{
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            {/*<ImageBackground source={{uri: require(__dirname + 'assets/background.png')}} resizeMode="cover">*/}
                    <AnimatedPressable
                        style={[
                            styles.defaultButton,
                            !isPressed ? styles.notPressedButton : styles.pressedButton,
                            { ...animatedSize }
                        ]}
                        onPress={() => {
                            setIsPressed(curr => !curr);
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                setIsPressed(curr => !curr)
                            }, 100);
                        }}
                    >
                        <Animated.Text style={[
                            styles.defaultText,
                            !isPressed ? styles.notPressedText : styles.pressedText,
                            {...animatedStyle}
                        ]}>Accept</Animated.Text>
                    </AnimatedPressable>
            {/*</ImageBackground>*/}
        </View>
    );
}
export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    defaultText: {
        fontSize: 11,
        fontFamily: 'Inter-Bold',
        textDecorationLine: 'underline',
        textTransform: 'uppercase'
    },
    notPressedText: {
        color: '#3C8C85',
    },
    pressedText: {
        color: '#58FFDC',
    },
    defaultButton: {
        width: 112,
        height: 36,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#58FFDC',
        borderRadius: 2.46
    },
    notPressedButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#58FFDC',
    },
    pressedButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#3C8C85',
    },
});


Thx so much for some help!
